# Line break in UILabel (Xcode 7 Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, xcode7

So I have an array of elements of type float. And I have a UILabel which is supposed to display each of these elements of the array on DIFFERENT LINES.

The Array is

```
var history = [Float]()
```

I used a for loop to go through each element and append it to the UILabel

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        currentString = String(history[i])
        result.text = result.text! + "\n" + currentString
    }
```

`result` is the UILabel.

I tried using \n but it doesn't seem to recognise it. Any solutions for this in Swift. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would check is if your label has (it is stupid mistake, but can happen to all of us)

```
  label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Assuming that is true, instead of building the string by hand, you could use in-built function join(). Sadly, since it is not String array, you can't use it directly, but you have to create string array first

```
  // Get both storages
  var history = [Float]() // Filled with your data
  var stringHistory = [String]()

  // Convert each number to string
  for value in history {
     stringHistory.append(String(value))
  }

  // Finally, join array to one string using \n as separator
  let finalString = "\n".join(stringHistory)
```

Hope some of this helps!

Comment: The numberOfLines can also be changed to 0 in the label's Attribute inspector instead of doing it programmatically. Of course assuming one is using the Interface Builder to add the UILabel. Note that it's simply called "Lines" in the Attributes inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below to solve your issue.

```
    let history = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    var result = ""
    self.lbl.text = ""
    for var i=0; i < history.count; i++
    {
        let currentString = NSString(format: "%.2f", history[i])
        self.lbl.text = self.lbl.text! + "\n" + (currentString as String)
    }
```

And Line Number should be 0. I set that from XIB.

Thanks